# Temporary failure resolving 'es.archive.ubuntu.com' on Ubuntu Server

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns

I have an Ubuntu server, but when I try to update I get this error

```
Err:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'es.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I know that the problem is DNS.

This is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 175.23.11.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 175.23.11.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

With `ifconfig` this is what I see:

```
eno1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:ba:db:32:f5:18  
      inet addr:175.23.11.2  Bcast:172.21.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a6ba:dbff:fe32:f518/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3269550 errors:0 dropped:35950 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:45180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:243192512 (243.1 MB)  TX bytes:65765157 (65.7 MB)
      Interrupt:16
```

Everything looks great but doesn't work.

```
root@server:/etc/network# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=4.11 ms

root@server:/etc/network# ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
root@server:/etc/network# ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

My `resolv.conf` is empty because the DNS conf is in interfaces file instead

Note: I have this file `resolv.conf` but not `resolvconf`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that all network traffic works properly except apt? Or are you saying that all network traffic is broken, including apt?

Comment: all is broken including apt yes